# APIs to handle the app resume in RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onresume, onpause, onsaveinstancestate

I have a RecyclerView :

```
class MyCustomRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(...) : RecyclerView(...)
{
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
        Log.i("MY_TAG", "onSaveInstanceState")
        return super.onSaveInstanceState()
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        Log.i("MY_TAG", "onRestoreInstanceState")
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        Log.i("MY_TAG", "onDetachedFromWindow")
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        Log.i("MY_TAG", "onAttachedToWindow")
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
    }
}
```

And I am using this RecyclerView in a Fragment

```
class MyCustomFragment: Fragment()
{
    override fun onResume()
    {
        super.onResume()
        startSomeWork()
    }

    override fun onPause()
    {
        super.onPause()
        stopSomeWork()
    }
}
```

On clicking the "home" button and launching the app again from the recent apps, the `onPause()` and `onResume()` APIs of the fragment are getting called and I am able to `startSomeWork()` and `stopSomeWork()`.

But I want to do the same thing from my RecyclerView instead. I tried to capture the logs of  some APIs mentioned above. On clicking the "home" button,`onSaveInstanceState()` is getting called. But when launching the app again from the recent apps, none of these APIs is getting called.

I would like to know if there are any such APIs which I can use for my purpose?

Comment: create startSomeWork() and stopSomeWork() functions in your adapter and call them from onResume and onPause. Alternatively, you can use livedata.

Comment: @AmarIlindra But ```onResume()``` and ```onPause()``` will again be of fragment right? I want to get rid of this dependency on fragment/activity.